# Google analytics tracking Http Https

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website with http and https access. (http://www.mywebsite.com, https://www.mywebsite.com)

Also, I have another website under https://www.mywebsite.com/myapplication

I need to set up Google analytics tracking for these websites.

Can I go along with a one tracking code?

Or do I have to get 3 tracking codes (as the analytics)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use one tracking code, the host doesn't matter, just make sure you're using Universal Analytics and not Classic Analytics.

The best test is to try it for yourself and see that you get hits correctly from both hosts.